# AWS CloudFront Signed URL results in Access denied in case of Alternate Domain Name and HTTPS

Tags: node.js, https, amazon-cloudfront, signed-url

I setup 4 CloudFront distributions all having the same S3 origin and all having Viewer Protocol Policy: HTTP and HTTPS. Their difference is in Alternate Domain Names and Restrict Viewer Access.

1. Distribution 1: Alternate Domain Names: **None**,  Restrict Viewer Access: **No**
2. Distribution 2: Alternate Domain Names: **None**,  Restrict Viewer Access: **Yes**
3. Distribution 3: Alternate Domain Names: **distribution3.example.com**,  Restrict Viewer Access: **No**
4. Distribution 4: Alternate Domain Names: **distribution4.example.com**,  Restrict Viewer Access: **Yes**

I uploaded an image to the S3 bucket (access to it is blocked) and tried to access it using the CloudFront distributions. When signing the URL, I used the same value for expiry (in a week), used the same public key in the same trusted key group, and signed all the URLs using the same code (using canned policy). My domain is registered with Cloudflare and its HTTPS certificate is Amazon Issue at AWS Certificate Manager. Here are results:

Distribution 1: Alternate Domain Names: **None**,  Restrict Viewer Access: **No**

```
http://distribution1.cloudfront.net/image.jpg -> 200 OK
https://distribution1.cloudfront.net/image.jpg -> 200 OK
```

Distribution 2: Alternate Domain Names: **None**,  Restrict Viewer Access: **Yes**

```
http://distribution2.cloudfront.net/image.jpg -> 403 Forbidden
https://distribution2.cloudfront.net/image.jpg -> 403 Forbidden
http://distribution2.cloudfront.net/image.jpg?Expires=XXX&Signature=XXX&Key-Pair-Id=XXX -> 200 OK
https://distribution2.cloudfront.net/image.jpg?Expires=XXX&Signature=XXX&Key-Pair-Id=XXX -> 200 OK
```

Distribution 3: Alternate Domain Names: **distribution3.example.com**,  Restrict Viewer Access: **No**

```
http://distribution3.cloudfront.net/image.jpg -> 200 OK
https://distribution3.cloudfront.net/image.jpg -> 200 OK
http://distribution3.example.com/image.jpg -> 200 OK
https://distribution3.example.com/image.jpg -> 200 OK
```

Distribution 4: Alternate Domain Names: **distribution4.example.com**,  Restrict Viewer Access: **Yes**

```
http://distribution4.cloudfront.net/image.jpg -> 403 Forbidden
https://distribution4.cloudfront.net/image.jpg -> 403 Forbidden
http://distribution4.example.com/image.jpg -> 403 Forbidden
https://distribution4.example.com/image.jpg -> 403 Forbidden
http://distribution4.cloudfront.net/image.jpg?Expires=XXX&Signature=XXX&Key-Pair-Id=XXX -> 200 OK
https://distribution4.cloudfront.net/image.jpg?Expires=XXX&Signature=XXX&Key-Pair-Id=XXX -> 200 OK
http://distribution4.example.com/image.jpg?Expires=XXX&Signature=XXX&Key-Pair-Id=XXX -> 200 OK
https://distribution4.example.com/image.jpg?Expires=XXX&Signature=XXX&Key-Pair-Id=XXX -> 403 -> Access denied XML page. WHY?
```

Why did the last case fail? Am I missing something?

The nodejs code used to generate signed URL is the same for all:

```js
fs = require('fs')
crypto = require('crypto')

const EXPIRES = 1624235093   // Mon Jun 21 2021 00:24:53 GMT+0000
const KEY_PAIR_ID = 'KUXXX'  // Cloudfront -> Key management -> Public keys
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('private_key.pem', 'utf8')

// Creating a signed URL using a canned policy
// https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-creating-signed-url-canned-policy.html
function createSignedURL(baseURL) {
  // canned policy
  const cannedPolicy = {
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Resource": baseURL,
        "Condition": {
          "DateLessThan": {
            "AWS:EpochTime": EXPIRES
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }

  // Remove white space (including tabs and newline characters) from the policy string
  const cannedPolicyString = JSON.stringify(cannedPolicy).replace(/[\s\t\n\r]/g, '')  
  // console.log(cannedPolicyString);

  // Sign policy with private key using RSA-SHA1, 
  // Base64-encode the string, 
  // Remove white space (including tabs and newline characters) from the hashed and signed string
  // Replace characters that are invalid in a URL query string with characters that are valid.
  const sign = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA1')
  sign.update(cannedPolicyString)
  sign.end()
  const signature = sign.sign(privateKey, 'base64').replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/=/g, '_').replace(/\//g, '~')
  // console.log(signature);

  // Creating a signed URL
  const signedURL = `${ baseURL }?Expires=${ EXPIRES }&Signature=${ signature }&Key-Pair-Id=${ KEY_PAIR_ID }`
  // console.log(signedURL);

  // return
  return signedURL
}

console.log(createSignedURL('https://distribution4.example.com/image.jpg'));
```

Comment: Could you post the code that generates the presigned url in the distro 4?

Comment: @jellycsc I added the code. It was the same for all signatures generated. They all worked except for the last one.

Comment: It seems that you are signing the http:// but trying to access via http**S**://

Comment: @anasqadrei Can you confirm you are signing the https version of the url^^?

Comment: @StefanN my function createSignedURL signs whatever URL it's getting whether it's http or https. I sign the https and access the https

Comment: @jellycsc yes I'm signing the https and it worked in many other cases as you see from the results above. It didn't work only in the last one

Comment: Can you send the full response that you get from CF and also also the logs from that CF distribution?

Comment: @StefanN the error is <Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access denied</Message></Error>. Nothing important in CF logs. It just says error.